# In "Curves and Surfaces" by Montiel and Ros, is $(dF_r)_p(e_i) = (1-rk_i(p))e_i$ correct?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, surfaces

Consider the following problem from Chapter 3 of *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd edition, by Montiel and Ros:

[image: Problem 16]

Now, for me it is easy to see that 
$$
(dF_r)_p(v) = v + r (dN)_p(v), \quad v \in T_pS.
$$
If $v = e_i$ is a principal direction, 
$$
(dF_r)_p(e_i) = (1 + rk_i)e_i.
$$

This differs from what the books asks us to show. What am I missing? Is it really a typo?

Comment: I have attempted to edit your title into something that is a bit more descriptive.  If I have not captured the crux of your problem, please edit the title to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We directly have that ${\rm d}(F_r)_p(v) = v+r\,{\rm d}N_p(v)$. So if ${\rm d}N_p(e_i) = -k_i(p)e_i$, we have that $${\rm d}(F_r)_p(e_i) = e_i - rk_i(p)e_i = (1-rk_i(p))e_i.$$The problem here is that the principal directions are the eigenvectors of the shape operator, and this is **minus** the differential of the Gauss map.

Comment: Shape operator is the second fundamental form?

Comment: No. It is minus the derivative of the Gauss map. Maybe they call it the Weingarten map there? It is the same thing.

Comment: (of course, the shape operator is the endomorphism corresponding to the second fundamental form under the isomorphism provided by the first fundamental form)

Comment: Actually they don't call it any special name. Thank you very much :)